# WebForms ReportViewer Datasource error

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I use ReportViewer control on my form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form>
```

Report file path initialized in page code file:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/Source/Untitled.rdlc";
}
```

When report renders, I got next error:

```
A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'.
```

Connection works normally (I tested it), and when I try to run my report in MS SQL Server Report Builder - it works normally too (report was generated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your rdlc report there is a dataset called "DataSet1" that you have added while designing the report. You need to pass the data this Dataset will use to render the report.

This is done through the localreport datasources collection. Note that it is plural meaning you can have more than one dataset in your report.

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "DataSet1";  //this is the name of the DataSet on your report rdlc
rds.Value = datatable; //this contains the data and columns referenced in the dataset

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
```

If you look at the tags below you will see what the reportviewer expects

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server">
<LocalReport ReportPath="Report1.rdlc">
    <DataSources>
        <rsweb:ReportDataSource Name="DataSet1" />
    </DataSources>
</LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

**Update**

For the second part, the datasource `DataSet11` has already been declared, just reference it in the codebehind passing the data as `Value`

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources["DataSet1"].Value = myData;
```

Comment: I have done second part of your answer (.aspx contents) - now i see navigation, but below displays error: 'An error has occurred during report processing. DataSet1' Should I do first part (codebehind) too?

Comment: I will update my answer to support the second part - codebehind is still needed

Comment: *'An error has occurred during report processing. DataSet1'* is probably because the path to the .rdlc file is not correct.

Comment: Path to the file is correct (if it is incorrect - how report viewer know about dataset name?). And what is myData? I created sql query that inside my report, what I should pass to it?

Comment: well I couldn't replicate the problem. there could be other issues causing that, but when I set this up, it worked as expected.

Comment: And what about ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources["DataSet1"].Value = myData; ? Why I should set data source when datasource is inside my report?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12810/discussion-between-evgeny-levin-and-tcoder)

Comment: that should be the object that holds your data e.g. datatable. The query you used in the report is for you to design the layout, specifying the columns to display and where to display them. It's not the actual data. `myData = getSomeDatafromDatabase("select * from table")`. The method could return a `DataTable` or `DataSet`. For DataSet, `mydata = myDataSet.Tables[0]'. Read on how to work with Dataset and Datatable